# Ruby or TSQL how to Find / Match matching pairs of comments block

Tags: sql, ruby, algorithm

I work on task how to mark  comments in old code (SQL, BXML, Json) so later I can use this info for parsing.  This is not my own env, so can't use native parsers alas, so I come up with this matrix approach, like in pic, the only thing left is to find how better find those  Start-End comments blocks, I create a script to fill this table to use.  I just hope that somebody knows how do it easy and flex, same way when you stay on parenthesis in NotePad ++  you can see matching pair.

I can use Ruby or SQL for that, I tried couple of paths but can't catch all cases yet. I plan to use offset index from start of the file, like Index = (line*100+pos) and then find next avail matching pair.
Appreciate your ideas

```
code line01
/*  comment01  */
code 
line02
  /*   comment02
       comment03
          /*   comment04  
          */  
   */
```

which can be presented in this matrix
[ScreenShot of matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moqTX.png)
* same for paste/copy

```
Char    Flag    Line    Pos Index   LineCont
/*  CommStart   2   1   201 /*  comment01  */
*/  CommEnd 2   16  216 /*  comment01  */
/*  CommStart   5   3   503   /*   comment02
/*  CommStart   7   11  711           /*   comment04 
*/  CommEnd 8   11  811 */
*/  CommEnd 9   4   904 */
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I can't use native parser". What's to stop you from downloading a robust parsing gem (like [Treetop](https://github.com/cjheath/treetop)) and copying it to whatever env it's needed on?

Comment: Tx Max, I'll check Treetop ,   * I meant native MS SQL Parser in C#. D

Comment: Tx again Max, it's new universe for me, never worked with gems. Best.M

Comment: I've checked github and other examples I found on http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/a-quick-intro-to-writing-a-parser-using-treetop.html  . Too much pieces to get a clear picture, I still not sure if it will work for my case, if I need let say find all active  occurrences of sql commands (*disregarding comments) in   MS SQL sp. Will this work ? Tx

Comment: I can see it works only for S-Expressions, and SQL is sp is not one.

Comment: Si, I see that this will be too much for my case,  Tx all for hlep